# Как использовать Costura.Fody?

Tags: c#, dll

Не могу найти что дальше делать для внедрения dll в exe после

```
> PM> Install-Package Costura.Fody
```

Как работает Costura.Fody?

**Обновлено:**

После добавления

```
<Target 
    AfterTargets="AfterBuild;NonWinFodyTarget"
    Name="CleanReferenceCopyLocalPaths" >
     <Delete Files="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(OutDir)%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Файл Resources\7z.dll остался но:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentException" в mscorlib.dll  >Дополнительные сведения: Путь имеет недопустимую форму.

```
var currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(Path.Combine(currentDir, @"Resources\7z.dll"));
```

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.TypeInitializationException" в
>   SevenZipSharp
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Инициализатор типа
>   "SevenZip.SevenZipLibraryManager" выдал исключение.

InnerException

> {"Путь имеет недопустимую форму."}

```
SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(@"Resources\7z.dll")
```

**Обновлено2:**

Ошибка исчезла после: ссылки-> SevenZipSharp -> Копировать локально-> False

```
SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(@"Resources\7z.dll")
```

Но по прежнему не работает:

```
var currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(Path.Combine(currentDir, @"Resources\7z.dll"));
```

Нужно как-то внедрить 7z.dll в exe

Comment: а...у вас есть зависимость от `7z.dll`...

Comment: Нужно было раньше об этом говорить. Завтра попробую разобраться как тут быть.

Comment: а зачем Вам внедрять 7z.dll в exe? почему бы просто не таскать её с собой вместе с exe?

Comment: Чтобы запускать с любого компьютера без копирования файлов в programs files

Answer (score 1):

Дальше вам делать ничего не нужно, просто собирайте проект как собирали раньше. Зависимые .dll будут вшиты в .exe файл.

Стоит отметить, что `Costura.Fody` по умолчанию не занимается очисткой папки от сторонних .dll. Чтобы изменить это поведение вы можете добавить следующие строчки в проектный файл

```
<Target 
    AfterTargets="AfterBuild;NonWinFodyTarget"
    Name="CleanReferenceCopyLocalPaths" >
     <Delete Files="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(OutDir)%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

или просто прописать соответствующую команду:

> Install-CleanReferencesTarget

Если вас интересует как это работает то вы можете поразбирать исходники. Они находятся [тут](https://github.com/Fody/Costura)

Comment: >Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentException" в mscorlib.dll

>Дополнительные сведения: Путь имеет недопустимую форму.

`var currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`

Comment: @codename0082016 как это связано с вопросом? Перестало компилироваться после добавления в проект `Fody`?

Comment: после добавления <Target